# How can we query in hibernate which returns a Map object?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity **Subscription** which has the following properties

name,BillOfLading,validTo (Date),ValidFrom (Date)

Sample Data:

```
Name  BillOfLading     ValidTo      ValidFrom
A       100101         1/28/2016    3/28/2017
A       100102         1/29/2016    3/29/2017
B       100103         1/30/2016    3/30/2017
C       100104         1/31/2016    3/31/2017
A       100105         1/28/2016    3/28/2017
```

Here I'm trying to get result in the form Map

```
Map<String,List<Subscription>>
```

The map contains a (key,value) pair,where  Name as key and List of subscriptions that belongs to specified name.

Suppose the Name **A** has 3 records So now the key will be **A** and value will be list of Subscriptions that belongs to **A**.

And also I need to sort Map based on the count of **A** subscription there in DB.

Note: The above is a shortened story of my scenario. So, I'm not putting my actual code.

Please help me if there is any possibility of returning Map in hibernate.

Comment: Are you using Hbm or jpa? Also can I suggest that you don't post client data, at least change their names.

Comment: I'm using Hbm. Actually, those are nowhere related client. I have picked that data randomly

Comment: Use the JPA and while fetch the values from DB using its will automatically sorted.

Comment: Expecting a solution in hibernate. I cant use JPA. Recently, We have shifted from JPA to hibernate. @Lova Chittumuri

Comment: AFAIK there is no solution for this in Hibernate. Something similar is done in this [blog post](http://blog.xebia.com/mapping-multimaps-with-hibernate/), but it uses a specialized MultiMap class (with sets instead of lists) and doesn't sort the contained sets.

Comment: have a look at:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html

Answer (score 1):

I dont see being possible to return `Map<String,List<Subscription>>` by a JPQL/HQL query.

I had return `Map`s from JPQL for example like this:

```
   @Query("SELECT new map(r.code, r.name) FROM Substance r GROUP BY r.code, r.name")
   List<Map<String, String>> select();
```

If you need a that complex return type have a look at Hibernate's [`ResultTransformer`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) interface and it's implementations, which can customize the result you want. I had never used this. There is a blog post which show the usage of this interface: [Why you should use the Hibernate ResultTransformer to customize result set mappings](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/)